# Dynamic RDF builder that takes an ontology and SQL result and builds tree

Tags: sql, semantics, rdf, jena, ontology

I've written a program that queries a large and messy sql database and then takes the resulting data and creates an RDF based on an ontology that was written by someone else and outputs a file of triples (using jena).

This works.  But the problem is I have to do a lot of tweaking to the code should the ontology be changed in some way (it's still under a lot of scrutiny), and I have to tweak the code further whenever the query changes (the data I'm querying is old and not clean, and it's unclear if I'm hitting the right tables at times).

Is there a tool or a trick that might make my life easier?

Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtuoso has the notion of RDF views that reside on top of a RDBMS (http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSSQL2RDF). This applies to external databases interfaceable via ODBC/JDBC. D2R Server also does something similar (http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/d2r-server/)

Comment: Virtuoso was actually something I've started investigating over the weekend!  What do you think of it?

But I'm also looking at D2RQ, have you used it/heard of it?  What did you think of it?